# This code does't work when my unity project is built

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

This code works in my unity project by pressing play, but this code doesn't work when I build it, why?

```
void ReadString()
{
    string path = "Assets\\Turkey\\daglar.txt";
    FileStream akis = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(akis, Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-9"), false);
    while (true)
    {
        dag = reader.ReadLine();

        if (dag != null)

            daglar.Add(dag);

        else break;
    }
    reader.Close();``
}
```

Comment: Saying your code *doesn't work* is not helpful. You need to explain **why** it doesn't work. What output do you expect? What output are you getting? Error messages? Please put more effort into your posts.

Comment: As @DavidG said, 'doesn't work' is too vague. Does the path not work?

Comment: path is work but dag string looks empty

Comment: You probably have a similar [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55076189/how-can-i-use-c-sharp-code-in-unity-to-work-in-mobile/55076827#55076827) Also are you building for Android or Windows?

Comment: error is caused by this code` 


StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(path, Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-9"),false);`



but this code is necessary for the Turkish character problem,what should i do?

Comment: i build for windows

Answer (score -1):

"Assets\Turkey\daglar.txt"; change to "Assets\Turkey\daglar.txt";

Why did you \ do 2 times?

Comment: You cant use asset path.
 txt file move to StreamingAsset folder or any android folder

Comment: You must create folder "Asset\StreamingAssets". txt file move to StreamingAssets folder. How to Access StreamingAsset folder is Application.streamingAssetsPath

Comment: i tried this code but it didn't work     string path = Application.streamingAssetsPath + "/sehirler.txt";